# Kotlin multiplatform library is not visible by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use [better-parse](https://github.com/h0tk3y/better-parse) library in the Kotlin multiplatform (JS/JVM) project and it's not visible in any module. [Link to sample project](https://github.com/llesha/MultiplatformGrammarSample).

Here is `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.6.20"
}
group = "llesha"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnit()
        }
    }
    js(IR) {
        browser()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse:0.4.4")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting
        val jsTest by getting
    }
}
```

I don't think that library is the problem, because it works in the Kotlin/JVM project with Kotlin 1.6.20.
Also it is shown in the External libraries as if it is imported:

[image: imported better-parse]

#### Attempts to make it work

I tried using `api` instead of `implementation`, moved dependency to the test module, moved dependencies to the root level like so:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    "commonMainImplementation"("com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse:0.4.4")
}
```

But none of that is working.

Also I noticed that if the library is added to the jvm module, it works. But in js module it does not. Here is a modified `sourceSets` script for this:

```kotlin
        ...
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-jvm:0.4.4")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.github.h0tk3y.betterParse:better-parse-js:0.4.4")
            }
        }
        ...
```

Comment: It works in the current version of Kotlin (1.8.10). Can you attach the link to a sample project?

Comment: @vanyochek tried setting 1.8.10 version in build.gradle.kts, it didn't help. Sample project link is added to the question.

Comment: It works on my machine. What version of IDE do you use? Do you have this problem during compilation?

Comment: I used 2021.1, but now switched to 2023.1 to see if it would help. I have this problem in the editor itself (it marks imports and library usages as unresolved references). But strangely, tests can be run and build works

Comment: Did the switching help?

Comment: It didn't I checked build in the previous IDE, it works too. But the problem with unresolved reference highlighting remains in both IDEs.

Comment: Can you try to `File | Repair IDE`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `Repair IDE` with all steps and Gradle rebuild did nothing.

Comment: Can you try to disable all third-party IDE plugins?

Comment: I do not have any...

Comment: Please, file an issue — https://kotl.in/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the kotlin version to `kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.9.22"` I made it work!